# Does C# have API that removes escaped JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a program where I receive JSON from a server of the format:

```
{
  "Parent1Key":"{\n   \"Child11Key\" : 0,\n   \"Child21Key\" : \"successfully.\"\n}\n",
  "Parent2Key":"{\n   \"child21\" : true,\n   \"Child22\" : \"successful.\"\n}\n"
}
```

This string is manually escaped in our program to be of the format:

```
{"Parent1Key":{ "Child11Key" : 0,    "Child21Key" : "successfully." },"Parent2Key":{ "child21" : true,    "Child22" : "successful." }}
```

Sorry, the specific code to make this change cannot be shared in this question.

so that we can pass it to our deserialize logic.

We are getting problem when we save strings with escaped characters like when **"child22" : "{text"**, or **"child22" : "text}"**.

Is there a C# API that removes the escaped JSON formatting correctly and returns the required string.

Comment: Yes, of course - Newtonsoft.Json can do that - and you should **never** do that escape/unescape manually

Comment: @SirRufo, how does Newtonsoft.Json do that, what API does it provide?

Comment: It can serialize/deserialize JSON and that is what you need

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like you have some JSON which has been constructed by serializing some objects (`Parent1Key` and `Parent2Key`), then taking those serialized strings, adding them to another object and serializing that.  So the inner objects end up double-serialized.

What you need to do is reverse that process by re-parsing the inner objects.  You can do that using [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
obj["Parent1Key"] = JObject.Parse((string)obj["Parent1Key"]);
obj["Parent2Key"] = JObject.Parse((string)obj["Parent2Key"]);
json = obj.ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/z2zpd5